# 2002 Honda Civic not starting

Tags: honda, starting, civic

My Honda stopped running, so I took it to a shop to get it fixed.

They replaced the fuel pump, spark plugs and put in a new battery. The compression is excellent.

Now, it still will not start. It cranks but will not start. Any ideas about the issue will be helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to the site. So does the car crank but not start?

Comment: So when you took delivery from shop to your home it worked? or is it still in the shop?

Answer (score 1):

If this is a standard transmission, check [the clutch pedal ignition switch](http://s639.photobucket.com/user/RonJ_HT/media/picture_5078.jpg.html). The switch may be bad or the rubber plug on the clutch lever may have deteriorated and the lever does not depress the switch. This happened on my 93 Civic and cost me $0.50 to get the new plug for the clutch lever.

Another thing to check is the [EFI relay](http://autorepair.about.com/od/enginetroubleshootin1/a/hon_mnrelay_tst.htm) Oten times the solder points in the relay go bad. This also happened on my 93 Civic.

Comment: If it were the clutch pedal switch, would the car even crank? On my 2006 Civic, if the clutch is not depressed, there's no cranking - you turn the key to Start and nothing happens.

Comment: My 93 was cranking, just wasn't starting. When I depressed the switch by hand the car started right up.